# How to make a second query offset -2 from current post

Tags: wp-query, loop

I would like a second `WP_Query` on a custom post type's single page to return 5 posts, starting with two before the current post, so that I get this:

1. The-one-before-the-previous post
2. Previous post
3. Current post
4. Next post
5. The-one-after-the-next post

How can I do this? `offset` is only good if I know the number of the current post.

In pseudo-code it's easy:

```
$gallery = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'artwork',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'fake-offset' => $current->ID-2 //This is imaginary
));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `offset` parameter, take a look at the `post_where` filter examples under the [Time Parameters section of WP_Query codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters). You could just add a filter that returns posts that are less than the current post's date.